# Wire Ceiling Fan and Exterior Lighting

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

**Objective**

I took down my old ceiling fan and tried to put in the new one but can't follow directions because I have two wire sets coming out of ceiling. **I'm trying to get one switch to turn on fan and other switch to turn on exterior lights.**

**Current Attempt**

The current setup is below, I can get the center switch to power the fan and the right switch to power the lights but the right switch seems to over ride the center switch because when it's on it powers off the fan.  I think this is close to the setup I need to be.

I can't get the image to load but basically the fan has a blue wire in addition to the white black and Neutral.  I wired the 3 white wires together, the 3 black wires together, the 3 neutral wires together and the red wire to the blue fan wire.

[image]

**General Setup**

The previous fan had one white wire with one black wire (I tagged both with tape) and then all remaining wires were with like colors.

out of the ceiling is two wire sets:

- set 1

  - White (w1)
  - Black (b1)
  - Red   (R1)
  - Copper (n1)
- set 2

  - White (w2)
  - Black (b2)
  - Copper (n2)
- The fan has 4 wires

  - White (w3)
  - Black (b3)
  - Blue. (U3)
  - Green. (N3)

I believe all the wiring needing to be done on the above but the switch info is below.  How do I wire this?

3 switches

- Right switch (for exterior lights) on/off single pole

  - White wire
  - Black wire
- middle switch (for fan) on/off single pole

  - Red wire
  - Black wire
- Left switch (for outlets) on/off 3 way

  - Red wire
  - Red wire
  - White wire

**Failed Attempts**

I tried connecting all whites, all neutrals, r1 to b2, the remaining blacks and blue but both of the switches turn on and off the fan and the exterior lights aren't switching on at all.

**Original old fan Setup**

The difference is the new fan also has a blue wire (so white Black neutral and blue)
[image]

Comment: The original wiring worked?  Were B1 and R1 connected together, or was one of them simply capped off?

Comment: B1 was possibly capped off but I'm no longer 100% sure of the original setup.  I do know for certain W1 was tied to B2 because I tagged them and generally other than that like colors were with like colors.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter, or voltmeter? It appears to me that "*Ceiling Wire 2*" might be a feed from the panel, can you confirm or deny this?

Comment: I have a tool that measures electrical output.  I don't know what or where the wires are coming from, I just know they were there.  Bought the house a year ago and just now working through this stuff.

Comment: Is the suggestion to untie B1, B2, or b3 from the other black wires and cap off?

Comment: I'd call in an Electrician.  If you can't remember the original wiring, and don't know how to determine where all the wires go/come from.  You're going to need more help than a bunch of crack pots on the Internet can provide.